# Pi 3 not connecting to Asus AC2900 Router with TP-Link Switch

Tags: router, ethernet, raspberry-pi, switch, network-interface

I've tried replacing the cable and switching ports on the switch but the Raspberry Pi 3 still won't show as a client in my Asus router dashboard. I was able to directly connect the Pi to the router which showed up as a client. However, I need to use the switch as it's being used by other clients.

I'm using the following setup:

- Asus AC2900 Router
- TP-Link TL-SG1008D 8-Port Switch
- Raspberry Pi 3 B+

The Pi is using the following network settings:

```
eth0 UP, lo UP
eth0
Static IP: 192.168.50.102
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.50.1
DNS: 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1
```